# converting float to integer giving an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in which few columns have data type float and when I tried to convert the datatype float to integer I am getting the below error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I have tried the below code to convert float to integer:

```
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].astype(np.int64)
```

Comment: df is None that's why, right way to do this is, check `if 'Amount' in df`, if present do what you are doing, else initialize `df['Amount']`

Comment: @drd if `df` is `None`, you cannot check `if  'Amount' in df`. You have to first check `if df`.

Comment: @Booboo, you are right. Missed a step there. `if df and if 'Amount' in df`

Answer (score 2):

use `dataFrame.dropna()` to remove the rows/columns with `None` in datatype

Read more here [dropna and similar function for DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)